# About TCP/IP: Is the message lost forever if the receiver system crashes halfway while receiving the message

Tags: asynchronous, tcp, synchronous

I have 2 newbie questions regarding about using TCP/IP to send message from System A to System B.

**Qns 1: Is message lost forever if system B crashes?**
1: System A sends a message to System B via TCP/IP transmission
2: System B receives the message and System B crashes while receiving the message halfway
3: If System B manage to recover in 2 minutes later, can system B receives the message again? (System A will only send once) Is the message lost forever?

**Qns 2: Does asynchronous or synchronous TCP/IP able to recover the message if System B crashes?**
This question is asked as I have people telling me that asynchronous or synchronous can perform message rollback. Not sure if they are confused with message queues.
I have read and google for information. It seems asynchronous or synchronous TCP/IP affects only how the data is sent to another system. It does not have the concept of rollback the message if System B crashes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

There are several reasons for this. First, TCP emulates a connection over IP. In reality, there is no connection, and *in principle* hosts or intermediate routers could indeed go down and reboot, and nobody would notice. Except... well, except when something is being sent, and except for another little detail.

For the in-order stream connection that TCP emulates, both sides must agree on (at least) a pair of ports and a sequence number. That happens during connection establishment.
After rebooting, the receiving machine no longer knows this information. Thus, packets that arrive are not meaningful to the network stack and are -- depending on firewall configuration -- either dropped silently, or an ICMP error 3 is sent back. In any case, no data is seen on the newly created socket.
This makes sense, too, since there are usually several (often a dozen and more) processes having network connections on a modern computer. Without knowing, which one should receive that data?

Also, intermediate routers will send back ICMP destination unreachable if a packet is sent to a host which is physically or logically unreachable (for example, cable unplugged or network card not up, no ARP entry, or getting an ICMP error 3 from the host itself). Receiving this message, the sender knows the receiver, and thus the connection, is dead.

Which means that if the sender is still sending the other half of your data or chooses to resend some unacknowledged data that timed out while the receiver is rebooting, it will inevitably detect that the receiver is dead.

There is no definite, mandatory recipe or formula for how exactly timeout happens (double the estimated RTT is one way of doing it, but something different is possible).
However, in any case, you can asssume it as pretty safe that *at least* one resend happens during a delay such as a reboot which involves at least 5 seconds of POST<sup>[1]</sup> and another 5-10 seconds of loading operating system and device drivers, bringing up the network device, obtaining IP address and such.

But let's assume 10 seconds, not minutes. That's a *awful lot of time*, and unless you are on a space ship on its way to Mars, your round trip times (and thus timeouts and resend intervals) will be a fraction of this. So the connection is practically guaranteed to be dead if any unacknowledged data remains (which was the precondition in your question).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> That is even optimistic, on some servers you can have 1-2 minutes of POST, without actually booting.

Comment: Hi thanks. is the response no referring to question 1or 2?

Comment: It is the response to both questions. TCP is always asynchronous, regardless of whether you use a synchronous or asynchronous API, and it behaves the same way in either case, with the same technical limitations.